# Tomcat regularly dies

Tags: shell, tomcat

I have tomcat installed on a linux server. Sometimes tomcat just dies. When i check the logs, it shows that tomcat is still running. So when i restart it anyways the application works. Sometimes the services on the server also stops working even though when i check the logs it shows all servcies are running. So I restart the services and then tomcat and everything works perfectly after that. My question is how do i figure out which one is causing the problem so that i can just restart only the services or just tomcat.

Comment: SO is for coding problem, so I think your question would have more chance on one of our sister site (ServerFault maybe ?). In any case, I would look in the OS logs for trace of the OOM killer action.

Comment: added a new ram put in last week.Thanks anyways. Ill try over at serverfault.